# Finding exact algorithm Efficiency and Big-O notation in nested loops

Tags: performance, algorithm, big-o

The efficiency of the algorithm `doIt` can be expressed as *O(n) = n^3*. Calculate the efficiency of the following program segment exactly. Then calculate the efficiency using the big-O notation. Show calculations.

```
for (i = 1; i <= n + 1; i++)
    for (j = 1; j < n; j++)
        doIt (...);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do **you** think the complexity is?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Big O, how do you calculate/approximate it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255/big-o-how-do-you-calculate-approximate-it)

Comment: I don't know what it is exactly, but I think the big-O notation would be n^4.

Comment: Well the outer (`i`) loop runs `n+1` times, and the inner (`j`) loop runs `n-1` times for each iteration of the outer loop - the product of those two counts is `n^2-1`, which is `O(n^2)`. If the function being called is `O(n^3)`, and you're running it `O(n^2)` times, it would seem to me the total complexity would be `O(n^3 * n^2)` or `O(n^5)`...

Answer (score 0):

There are two for loops each iterating (almost) n times. So `O(n^2)` for them.

A method of `O(n^3)` is called (almost) `n^2` times, then you will have `n^2 * n^3` which will eventually get you to :

`O(n^5)`